# Mathematical operation on a dictionary list (Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6 and I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
list = [{'name': 'A', 'number':'1'}, {'name': 'B', 'number':'2'}, {'name': 'C', 'number':'3'}, {'name': 'D', 'number':'4'}]
```

I found out how to print the list in the desired format with:

```
for s in list:
     name = s['name']
     number = s['number']
     print(name + " = "+ number)
```

Which gives:

> A = 1
> B = 2
> C = 3
> D = 4

I would like to be able to multiply the items 'number' by 2 for example and display:

> A = 2
> B = 4
> C = 6
> D = 8

Thank you!

Comment: `print(name + " = "+ number * 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

You're able to multiply a number by using the `*` symbol `2 * 2` will output 4.

Because your values are stored as Strings you'll need to convert them to Integers first. `int('2') * 2 == 4`.

Then to print an Integer with a string you need to convert it back to a string.

for the last line change it to

```
print(name + " = "+ str(int(number)*2))
```

Comment: Best to elaborate how/why that works. Why a string must be an int to multiple

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to temporarily multiply the values and print them out? Which in this case, you would change your last line to

```
print(name + " = "+ int(number) * 2)
```

However, if you want to multiply the values in your dictionary directly, you would go about it as so:

```
for s in list:
 name = s['name']
 s['number'] = str(int(s['number']) * 2)         # multiply value by 2
 number = s['number']
 print(name + " = "+ number)
```

Note that your problem may arise from the fact that your dictionary values are stored as strings instead of integers, which means that to perform any kind of mathematical operation on them, you must convert them to an integer and back to a string.

Comment: `print(name + " = "+ int(number) * 2)` wont work because you can't concat string with integer, use `print(name, "=", int(number) * 2)` instead or `print(name + " = "+ str(int(number) * 2))`.

Comment: My bad, got confused with Java for a sec there haha :D

Answer (score 0):

You can always iterate over your list to modify the value of its nested parts, i.e.:

```
your_list = [{'name': 'A', 'number': '1'},
             {'name': 'B', 'number': '2'},
             {'name': 'C', 'number': '3'},
             {'name': 'D', 'number': '4'}]

for item in your_list:  # iterate over each dictionary in your_list
    # since your dict contains strings we have to convert the value into a number/integer
    # before multiplying it by 2
    item["number"] = int(item["number"]) * 2  # turn it back to a string with str() if needed

# now, let's demonstrate that the data changed in `your_list`:
for item in your_list:  # iterate over each dictionary in your_list
    print("{} = {}".format(item["name"], item["number"]))  # print in your desired format
# A = 2
# B = 4
# C = 6
# D = 8
```

Comment: Why don't you combine those two for loop so you print it after multiply it immediately?

Comment: @fahadh4ilyas - Because printing is just a demonstration/verification of the data change, I reckon it has little practical use other than to show what occurred with the data. But, point taken, I'll add an appropriate comment.